# PHP Install on IIS 7, no test results

Tags: php, iis-7, installation

I am trying to install PHP on my IIS web server running version 7.0.  I downloaded the php-7.1.8 Non Thread Safe for Windows 64.  I then procceded to follow the steps found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/.

I had no issues with the install but when it came to the last step of creating the test PHP page and launching, instead of getting the results, i'm being asked to Open or save the file??

I've also tried putting this into a live website and accessing it outside the web server.  When I try this I receive a 500 - Internal Server Error.

I had tried this about a year or two ago and got frustrated, so I gave up and have retried today but experiencing about the same result.  Don't know what other information would help, but i'm willing to provide what's necessary.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing research I ended up using the Windows Installer version (https://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx) and then went back through the configuration steps of the php.ini file.